# sql query get count and variance percentage based on month

Tags: sql

I have a table with data similar to the following:

```
column1            column2
Landing Permit     4/5/2015
Landing Permit     4/6/2015
Landing Permit     4/7/2015
Landing Permit     4/5/2014
Landing Permit     4/6/2014
Landing Permit     4/7/2014
Message            4/5/2015
Message            4/6/2015
Message            4/7/2015
Message            4/5/2014
Message            4/6/2014
Message            4/7/2014
```

I need to calculate the variance based on 15 and 14 difference from column2. I want to get output similar to the following:

```
        May                    June                 July
               output/variance     output/variance     output/variance
Landing Permit 1/some%               1/some%             1/some%     
Message        1/some%               1/some%             1/some%
```

How would I go about accomplishing that?

Comment: Please provide us with a minimal, complete and verifiable example [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What kind of queries have you tried?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: SELECT column1,COUNT(*) as productcount, ROUND(100.0*COUNT(column1)/(SELECT 100.0* count(column1)  FROM table),3) as percentage  
FROM table GROUP BY column1

this returns me variance based on clolimn1, but i need to get by month with year difference

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would first match up the columns with a self join like this

```sql
SELECT
    a.column1
  , a.column2
  , b.column2
FROM
    Test a
JOIN
    Test b 
ON 
    YEAR(a.column2) = YEAR(b.column2)+1
AND MONTH(a.column2) = MONTH(b.column2)
AND DAY(a.column2) = DAY(b.column2)
AND a.column1 = b.column2
WHERE
    YEAR(a.column2) = 2014
```

After this you can just select whatever you want and do your calculations with something similar to this as a CTE.